# Django - Getting parameters from URL

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am passing the parameters in URL to my view like this:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/cars/?model_number=13375
```

and getting it like this:

```
class GetCarDetails(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        model_number = "";
        if request.GET.get('model_number'):
            model_number = request.GET.get('model_number')
```

But I want to pass it now like this:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/cars/13375/
```

And I want Django to treat the `13375` like model number

Comment: Read django tutorial. You need to change urls.py for this. And then you will get params in `kwargs`.

Comment: Read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define it at the url's:

```
url(r'^cars/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.GetCarDetails.as_view(), name="getcardetails"),
```

And in your views:

```
class GetCarDetails(View):

    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GetCarDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["model_number"] = self.kwargs['pk'];
        return context
```

As told by @Anentropic in comments, more detailed info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: And how will I access this returned context in my `def get(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: I guess you can use it in the same way there: self.kwargs['pk'];